# Partial View not refreshing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dialog, partial-views

My Controller method is

```
public ActionResult Index(string id = "All")
{
    ViewBag.RefType = new SelectList(rep.getReferenceType());
    List<Reference> reference = rep.getReference(id);

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView("_ReferenceList", reference);
    else
    {
        ViewBag.domain = "All";
        return View(reference);
    }
}
```

Second method calls the index

```
public ActionResult EditReference(Reference rf, int Dom)
{
    Reference rf1 = null;
    string dom = "";
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        rf1 = rep.UpdateReference(rf);
        if (Dom == 0)
        {
            dom = "All";
        }
        else
        {
            dom = rf1.Domain;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id =dom});
    }
    return View(rf1);
}
```

and my view is

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditReference", "Reference", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "closeDialog()", LoadingElementId = "divLoading" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    Html.RenderPartial("_Reference");     
}
```

The problem is that the new edited data doesnt appear once the dialog is closed ...It displays the same old data...I tried another function

```
function closDlgAndRefresh{
 $('.Dialog').dialog('close');
            $('.ddlRndrPrtl').val($('.ddlRndrPrtl').val());
            $('.ddlRndrPrtl').trigger('change');
}
```

and when I call this function onSuccess it does displays the data but the Index function is called twice which I don't wana do...Once when Index function is called from Edit function and 2nd when dropdown is triggered...

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed....

Forgot to add Updated TargetID in Ajax.BeginForm

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditReference", "Reference", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",  LoadingElementId = "divLoading", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "DivTbl_Reference" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

  Html.RenderPartial("_Reference");     
}
```